# PROC HTTP equivalent of curl option --insecure/-k

Tags: http, sas

I can access a REST API using curl by sending a system command and using `pipe` as below

```
filename fn pipe "curl -k -u &user.:&pass. 'https://blahblah.com/rest/api/content/108428908/child/attachment' ";

data new;
infile fn;
input;
put _infile_;
run;
```

This works, but I'd like to use PROC HTTP so I get the response back in a .json file rather than in the log, and I can use SAS password encryption. Here's my PROC HTTP code:

```
filename out "/blah/blahblah/output.json";

proc http
  url    = 'https://blahblah.com/rest/api/content/108428908/child/attachment'
  method = "GET"
  webusername = "&user"
  webpassword = "&pass"
  out    = out
  ;
run;
```

This works as far as giving me a json file, but the json file I get back says "User not permitted to view attachments on content", which is the response I was getting from curl before adding the `-k` option (i.e. `--insecure`).

So how can I do the equivalent of `-k` in PROC HTTP? (Tell SAS not to check the SSL Cert). Modifying any options outside of those which can be specified within the .SAS file is not an option, as I don't have the access to change those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is setting the [SSLREQCERT](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=secref&docsetTarget=n122o5839nip32n1o41yxejik0nu.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) flag an option? According to [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Administration-and-Deployment/PROC-HTTP-with-insecure-SSL-certicates/td-p/460360) it looks like you can use the `ALLOW` option to tell the server to allow connections that fail the SSL handshake.

Comment: I don't think you can set that option within the code. I get "ERROR 13-12: Unrecognized SAS option name SSLREQCERT.". I think you have to set it in the config file (?). For that reason, it doesn't work for me. +1 for a good answer for others who might see this question though.

Comment: @Ryan You'd have to set it in the config file, yes (or at invocation through command line).

Comment: I think setting at invocation can be done even through Windows, add the relevant code to your shortcut reference.This paper explains how that can be set: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1190-2017.pdf

Comment: SSLREQCERT is set as an environment variable, not as a option.  Thus the correct syntax for appending to the command line is using the SET option i.e. -set SSLREQCERT "ALLOW".  As the documentation clearly states, this only works with unix.  While you can set in under Windows, if you try to execute PROC HTTP you will get a note stating that SSLREQCERT is ignored "NOTE: The SSLREQCERT option is not valid on Windows. The SSLREQCERT value will be ignored."

Answer (score 2):

The most correct answer here is to NOT ignore the SSL issue and instead add the certificate to the appropriate trust manager/key store on the machine where you are running PROC HTTP.  The method by which to do this varies by OS and SAS version.  [This documentation page will provide some insight into how to do this.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/69831/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0n1y5gwevy312n13h5bm4yf6quy.htm)